# Set current Time.zone in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

Javascript on my page saves client UTC offset to the cookie.
How do I use this cookie to create a TimeZone and assign it to Time.zone ?

I need something like:

```
before_filter :set_time_zone

def set_time_zone
  Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('my timezone', cookies[:timezone])
end
```

except that the right part of this expression does not work and I'm not sure if I'm going the right way here. Can't get it.

Comment: Be warned that `Time.zone =` will set the timezone globally (not just for this request); you should stick to `Time.use_zone` and pass a block to ensure the zone affects this request only. This works really well with rails' `around_action` instead of the `before_action`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's the working googled answer:

```
min = cookies[:timezone].to_i
Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[-min.minutes]
```

Just to make it clear, the javascript part:

```
if(!($.cookie('timezone'))) {
  current_time = new Date();
  $.cookie('timezone', current_time.getTimezoneOffset(), { path: '/', expires: 10 } );
}
```

Comment: You may also need to remove that >>> if(!($.cookie('timezone'))) <<<  condition, as your site visitors may travel and there need to refresh their timezone value.

Comment: One little problem: the `TimeZone[-min.minutes]` returns first available timezone with the `min.minutes` offset. For example, for Tokyo it returns Irkutsk. So this method would work if you don't need to display timezone name or code.

Comment: @arkadiy is right, but this is not only a _little problem_ because you can get time zones that are not observing daylight saving time (DST). In this case the result is a wrong time.

Moreover `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` returns the current offset including DST but the `ActiveSupport::TimeZone[]` selection expects the standard timezone offset so you should update your javascript function [like this](http://bit.ly/timezone_js).

You can see [this thread](https://github.com/potomak/tomatoes/issues/8#issuecomment-2167461) about the issue if you want to know more about it.

Answer (score 6):

@snitko - you're answer worked great for me for a long time. However, as @Giovanni pointed out, it doesn't account for daylight savings time in some scenarios since it pulls the first timezone available given the minute offset. I've found a simple working answer that accounts for DST.

Head here - http://site.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript, it's a javascript timezone detector. You simply copy the javascript code linked from the website (or right [here](http://cdn.bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/downloads/jstz.min.js)) into your one of your app's javascript files (application.js works fine). It allows you to retrieve the timezone through an object named `jstz`.

Then, in application.html.erb I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var timezone = jstz.determine();
  document.cookie = 'time_zone='+timezone.name()+';';

</script>
```

And in application_controller.rb, I have

```
before_filter :set_timezone 

private
def set_timezone
  Time.zone = cookies["time_zone"]
end
```

And that's all you need! Time zone is set properly for your Rails app.

EDIT: It's possible you need to place the javascript cookie setting code after your `<\body>` tag in application.html.erb due to the different way and order javascript files are loaded up.

Comment: Hey, I know its a long time.. but Im doing this. Could you clarify the last line? And do you not have to refresh the page once you set the cookie, to affect the current page?

Comment: The last line sets the Time Zone as a global configuration for your application. If you have a lot of people hitting your application from different timezones, this might not be the best approach (compared to setting the Time Zone on an individual User). But yes you are correct, you'd need to refresh the page so the server renders the page with the updated Time Zone to see any Time related changes.

Comment: Hey, I believe Time.zone is thread safe, and as long as you set it on every request, I dont think should interfere between requests right? Also I actually meant your EDIT: line which talks about placing the cookie stuff at the end?

Comment: Ah. Ya I don't remember why I added the EDIT. It's been a long time but I was building a Rails application at the time and I believe I ran into an issue where the code wasn't being run unless it was after the `</body>` tag.

Comment: ah ok, no worries, its working for me at the head of the page, on dev atleast

Answer (score 3):

When I have it stored in my User model it is as simple as this

```
def set_time_zone
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone unless current_user.blank?
end
```

so maybe you could do

```
def set_time_zone
  Time.zone = cookies[:timezone]
end
```

That's untested, I've never tried to do it from a cookie, I think it makes more sense to store it in the User model.

Comment: No, I don't need to store it in the user model.
Anyway, what your current_user.time_zone looks like? Is it a String?

Comment: Yes, just using the Rails built in time zone stuff, so for my user in an app it would just be "Sydney"

Comment: Generally, accessing objects like session and cookie in Model (M part of MVC) is not a good practice

Comment: As I see, you are using set_time_zone method as before_filter in applicaton_controller.rb but this is wrong way to set time zone for application because Time.zone is global object and zone is global property. You need to use around_filter something like this:                      def set_time_zone
    old_time_zone = Time.zone
    if current_user
      Time.zone = current_administrator.time_zone
    end
    yield
  ensure
    Time.zone = old_time_zone
  end