# Fullcalendar time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I have a RoR app using Fullcalendar - running on Heroku.
The calendar view shows an event as 9am - 10am.  When I view a list of the time, I get 4p - 7pm.

Does it has something to do with timezone?

I tried setting ignoreTimeZone true and then false:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar
    editable: true,
    ignoreTimezone: true,
    header:
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    defaultView: 'month',
    height: 500,
    slotMinutes: 30,
```

Thanks for the help!

Here is an example - the database record has start_at 16:00 (4pm) but the Fullcallendar view shows it starting at 9am

Comment: How is the time set in the events? Are you using UTC offsets?

Comment: I'm using arshaw Fullcalendar.  It supplies the fields starts_at and ends_at.  I'm saving those fields into a RoR pg database.

Comment: Ah, I see now. You are talking about the view times, not the event ones. Can you post the code where you are listing the times?

Comment: Fullcalendar contains the code to display the events.  All I have on the page is: <div id='calendar' style="width: 700px"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixed the problem:

$ heroku config:add TZ=America/Denver

Answer (score 0):

Your events list (index.html.erb or the like) shows UTC times while fullcalendar shows times in your browser's detected timezone.

In order to fix this, you should set the timezone of each request thread to the user's timezone. This should work:

In your events controller, add this:

```
before_filter set_time_zone

def set_time_zone
    (...)
end
```

Checkout the rest of the code in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/942865/336806

There's also this neat gem that I'm using myself:

https://github.com/scottwater/detect_timezone_rails